# Arrange tasks in a certain order in python

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a dict describing a bunch of jobs, which will be processed in a certain order:

```py
jobs = {
"job_a": {"commands": ["ls -a", "echo $LANG"], "dependencies": []}
"job_b": {"commands": ["ps aux", "find -name xxx"], "dependencies": []}
"job_c": {"commands": ["umask", "cat yyy"], "dependencies": ["job_a"]}
"job_d": {"commands": ["kill -9 www", "sed zzz"], "dependencies": ["job_b", "job_c"]}
}
```

The dependencies list in each job item determine the order they should be executed: such as `job_d` should be done after `job_b` and `job_c`.

What I need is a list indicates these jobs' order, in above example, the list could be

```py
jobs_order = ["job_a", "job_b", "job_c", "job_d"]
# or 
jobs_order = ["job_a", "job_c", "job_b", "job_d"]
# or 
jobs_order = ["job_b", "job_a", "job_c", "job_d"]
```

The simplest approach is to traverse the `jobs.items()` list over and over, and inserting the dependants into front positions at each time.

The amount of jobs here could be very large. Could we do it better with smaller space and shorter time?

Comment: Look into making a DAG while iterating over the keys and the elements in `dependencies` list say using https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/dag.html

Comment: A basic depth first search can do the trick.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, thanks for your key word, but can the DAG algorithm be implemented without third party modules?

Comment: Yes, you can create your own Grap Node class and use that to build your DAG and applying a DFS

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Topological Sort", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: @Spike If you have ever installed something with `apt-get` or a similar package manager, that's what it does when resolving dependencies (i.e. what must be installed first). You can check one of the solutions here https://www.electricmonk.nl/docs/dependency_resolving_algorithm/dependency_resolving_algorithm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may look like this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from collections import defaultdict
from queue import SimpleQueue


def get_order(jobs):
    q = SimpleQueue()
    subtasks = defaultdict(list)
    n_deps = {}
    for key, job in jobs.items():
        dependencies = job.get('dependencies', [])

        n_deps[key] = len(dependencies)
        if len(dependencies) == 0:
            q.put(key)

        for parent in dependencies:
            subtasks[parent].append(key)

    order = []
    while not q.empty():
        job = q.get()
        order.append(job)
        for key in subtasks[job]:
            n_deps[key] -= 1
            if n_deps[key] == 0:
                q.put(key)

    return order


def main():
    jobs = {
        "job_d": {"commands": ["kill -9 www", "sed zzz"], "dependencies": ["job_b", "job_c"]},
        "job_c": {"commands": ["umask", "cat yyy"], "dependencies": ["job_a"]},
        "job_b": {"commands": ["ps aux", "find -name xxx"], "dependencies": []},
        "job_a": {"commands": ["ls -a", "echo $LANG"], "dependencies": []},
    }
    print(get_order(jobs))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
['job_b', 'job_a', 'job_c', 'job_d']
```